# ViewGroup.addview() is working but child view is not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I develop an android app. I want to add TextView(s) to a LinearLayout dynamically. No error occurred but TextView is not showing. I thought sleep_records_container' height might be 0dp and I tried to set 300dp but nothing showed in this container. How do I solve this problem?

Below Fragment is aim to show sleep records in one month.

SleepRecordFragment.kt

```
package com.example.sleeprecorder.sleeprecord

import android.annotation.SuppressLint

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.view.size
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.sleeprecorder.R
import com.example.sleeprecorder.database.SleepRecorderDatabase
import com.example.sleeprecorder.databinding.FragmentSleepRecordBinding
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class SleepRecordFragment: Fragment() {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "onCreateView called")
        val binding = FragmentSleepRecordBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        //val binding : FragmentSleepRecordBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_sleep_record, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource = SleepRecorderDatabase.getInstance(application).sleepRecordDao

        val viewModelFactory = SleepRecordViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

        val sleepRecordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(SleepRecordViewModel::class.java)





        binding.sleepRecordViewModel = sleepRecordViewModel
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        sleepRecordViewModel.oneMonthSleepRecords.observe(this, Observer { oneMonthSleepRecords ->
            Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "oneMonthSleepRecords.size: ${oneMonthSleepRecords.size}")

            binding.sleepRecordsContainer.removeAllViews()
            oneMonthSleepRecords.forEach { sleepRecord ->
                Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "Observe oneMonthSleepRecords: ${sleepRecord.toString()}")



                val startSleepTextView = TextView(context)
                startSleepTextView.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                startSleepTextView.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                val startSleepDate = Date(sleepRecord!!.startTimeMilli)
                val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                val startSleepText = getString(R.string.start_sleep_datetime, formatter.format(startSleepDate))
                startSleepTextView.text = startSleepText
                Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "start sleep text: ${startSleepText}")

                val sleepRecordLinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                sleepRecordLinearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                sleepRecordLinearLayout.addView(startSleepTextView)
                binding.sleepRecordsContainer.addView(sleepRecordLinearLayout)

            }

            Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "size in sleep record container: ${binding.sleepRecordsContainer.size}")
        })



        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val thisYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val thisMonthIndex = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)

        sleepRecordViewModel.setThisYearMonth(thisYear, thisMonthIndex)


        binding.yearMonth.text = getYearMonthStr(thisYear, thisMonthIndex)
        binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.year, thisYear)
        binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.month_index, thisMonthIndex)
        Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "tag year: ${binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.year)}")
        Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "tag month index ${binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.month_index)}")



        binding.addSleepRecord.setOnClickListener {
            this.findNavController().navigate(SleepRecordFragmentDirections.actionSleepRecordFragmentToAddSleepFragmentRecord())
        }

        binding.goToNextMonth.setOnClickListener {
            val shownYear = binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.year).toString().toInt()
            val shownMonthIndex = binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.month_index).toString().toInt()
            Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "shownYear: ${shownYear}")
            Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "shownMonthIndex: ${shownMonthIndex}")


            val calendarToNextMonth = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendarToNextMonth.set(Calendar.YEAR, shownYear)
            calendarToNextMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, shownMonthIndex)
            calendarToNextMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)

            val yearMonthStr = getYearMonthStr(calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))


            Log.i("SleepRecordFragment", "next month: ${yearMonthStr}")
            binding.yearMonth.text = yearMonthStr
            binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.year, calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR))
            binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.month_index, calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))

            sleepRecordViewModel.onChangeMonth(calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarToNextMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        }

        binding.goToPreviousMonth.setOnClickListener {
            val shownYear = binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.year).toString().toInt()
            val shownMonthIndex = binding.yearMonth.getTag(R.id.month_index).toString().toInt()
            val calendarToPreviousMonth = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendarToPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.YEAR, shownYear)
            calendarToPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, shownMonthIndex)
            calendarToPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)

            val yearMonthStr = getYearMonthStr(calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))
            binding.yearMonth.text = yearMonthStr
            binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.year, calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR))
            binding.yearMonth.setTag(R.id.month_index, calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))

            sleepRecordViewModel.onChangeMonth(calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarToPreviousMonth.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        }





        return binding.root
    }

    private fun getYearMonthStr(year: Int, monthIndex: Int): String {
        val yearStr = year.toString()
        val monthStr = (monthIndex + 1).toString()
        val zeroPaddingMonthStr = "00${monthStr}".substring("00${monthStr}".length - 2)


        return "${yearStr}/${zeroPaddingMonthStr}"
    }


}
```

fragment_sleep_record.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="sleepRecordViewModel"
            type="com.example.sleeprecorder.sleeprecord.SleepRecordViewModel" />

    </data>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sleep_record_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/year_month_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/go_to_previous_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_previous_month"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/year_month"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/year_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/go_to_previous_month"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/go_to_next_month"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/go_to_next_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_next_month"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/year_month"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_sleep_record"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/add_sleep_record"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/year_month"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sleep_records_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Now you are adding TextView in a function "addView".
You need to add a layout.

Comment: ```val sleepRecordLinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)
                sleepRecordLinearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                sleepRecordLinearLayout.addView(startSleepTextView)
                binding.sleepRecordsContainer.addView(sleepRecordLinearLayout)```

Is that correct? But result is not changed.

Comment: sleepRecordLinearLayout.addView(startSleepTextView)   
Please remove this one.

Comment: I removed it but I want to add texts to ScrollView.

Comment: You need to add a layout that contains the TextView.

so you will create new layout, and TextView in the layout.
And then you can add the layout as a "addView()"

Comment: What is different between your comment and above code in my comment?

Comment: this is a record_cell layout.

<Linearlayout ... >
   <TextView ..../>
</LinearLayout>

- Get inflate
- Get record_cell  View from inflate
- Edit textview value of record_cell 
- Add record_cell  View as a addView


if it's not enough, I will post an example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `WRAP_CONTENT` via `layoutParams` as follows.

```
    val startSleepTextView = TextView(context)
    //startSleepTextView.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    //startSleepTextView.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    startSleepTextView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Comment: I tried it and solved. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You did not inflate the Layout it looks like from your code: If you want to set the binding layout you might want to do something like:

```
binding = Layout.inflate(inflator, container, false)
```

As I do not know what kind of layout you are using I am just substituting with a generic layout. If you use Navi view you will get different answer than FragmentManager.

Comment: I wrote assignment binding variable as ```val binding = FragmentSleepRecordBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)```
Is something different between your code and mine?

Comment: Please post the whole code so we can see, I cant find the binding in your code.

Comment: I posted whole code of SleepRecordFragment.kt.